# SQL Optimization where clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Instead of using function in the where clause can we do something different.

DateAdd taking time poor performance i guess..

How to optimize this sql

```
SELECT cust_id, order_date, price
FROM customers
WHERE DATEADD(DD,50,order_date)>=GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't run your function on `order_date`, run the inverse on `getdate()` instead

```
select cust_id, order_date, price
from customers
where order_date>=dateadd(Day,-50,getdate())
```

Function calls on `order_date` are going to cause an index scan, if you instead run your function on the filter criteria `getdate()` you can preserve an index seek on this column. (If it has an index).

[SARGable functions in SQL Server - Rob Farley](http://blogs.lobsterpot.com.au/2010/01/22/sargable-functions-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Yes, if you create an index on order_date column.

Comment: where order_date < =dateadd(Day,-50,getdate()) or where order_date >=dateadd(Day,-50,getdate())

Comment: that way it only has to do the calculation once for the current date.  Should be faster.

Comment: @user1810575 `order_date>=dateadd(Day,-50,getdate())` is the equivalent of what you have in your question. `order_date` 50 days old and newer

Comment: You can try assigning dateadd(Day,-50,getdate()) to a variable before hand so that per each record this also need not be evaluated.

Comment: @Sam in this case, `dateadd(Day,-50,getdate())` will be processed as a runtime constant, but it is good to be careful about such things. See [this answer on dba.stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18461/43889) for more information.

Comment: @SqlZim This one is new to me and yup you're quite correct. Thanks for that info and for anyone who might want to know a bit more found this https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175933(v=sql.105).aspx link as well.